# AngularJS - ng-repeat with carousel

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, carousel

I tried to make the carousel with ng-repeat. The image loads successfully, but the previous and next button do not work. 
Here is my code

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item {{::($index === 0 ? 'active' : '')}}" ng-repeat="movie in popularMovies track by $index">
      <div class="row">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{movie.image}}" alt="{{movie.name}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: well your next/previous button should do something - there I do not see that they are updating anything in your angular context. Maybe you should have a property of what's the current movie being displayed (index), and on ng-click of previous/next buttons update that value?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your Angular Elements to the below code and it will work.

I guess your next and previous were not working because there might be few errors in importing `js` files

Let me know if this fixes your problem.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">

      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_1280.jpg" alt="{{movie.name}}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">

      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt="{{movie.name}}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```